# Uitable view custom cell is not getting selected at all

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I created a custom tableView cell and I can see my tableView with the desired custom cell. Now the problem is I am not able to select my table row. I tried to display console output from within `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 but It never fets called. I am confused. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Following is my Customized cell class:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        // Initialization code

        CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
        CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

        _title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boundsX +70, 5, 100, 25)];
        _title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        _title.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        _details = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boundsX + 70, 30, 100, 15)];
        _details.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        _details.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

        _duration = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boundsX + 200, 10, 65, 15)];
        _duration.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        _duration.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

        _price = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boundsX + 180, 30, 80, 15)];
        _price.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        _price.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

        _listingImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boundsX +10, 0, 50, 50)];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_title];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_details];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_price];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_duration];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_listingImage];

        [_title release];
        [_details release];
        [_duration release];
        [_price release];
        [_listingImage release];

    }

    return self;

}
```

Below is my `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    CustomizedCell *cell = (CustomizedCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomizedCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     //   cell = [[[CustomizedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    ADJListing *listing = [self.dataSource.listings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


    cell._title.text = listing.title;
    cell._details.text = listing.details;
    cell._price.text = [listing.price stringValue];
    cell._duration.text = (NSString*) listing.start_datetime;
    cell._listingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

Again this is my `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"data");

    detailedVC = [[DetailedViewController alloc] init];
    detailedVC.dataSource = self.dataSource;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedVC animated:YES];
    [detailedVC release];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I somehow had self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO and i missed it. Its working fine now. Thanks

Comment: weird, I had the same problem. After playing with the XIB file a bit I had to explicitly set this property, even tough it's YES as default!

Answer (score 0):

Try deselecting the row after the rest of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is called.

Also, have you declared your UITableViewController subclass as the tableview's delegate? It's easiest to do this in IB. If this isn't a UITableViewController subclass, you'll need to implement the UITableViewDelegate yourself by declaring it in your header file.

Comment: Hi W Dyson. Thanks for the reply. I tried it too. but no change. also its a UIViewController subclass and I have declared UITableViewDelegate myself in header file and also I have set the delegate of the tableView as self.

Comment: Hi guys. I got it. I somehow had self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO and i missed it. Its working fine now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi check with the xib files.
go to .xib, select your view and in the right panel, check for "User Interaction Enabled".